# 3 characters search on a shared hosting mysql

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, hosting, shared

I need to do a 3 chars search with mysql.

On a dedicated server, I'd change `ft_min_word_len=3` on the `my.cnf` file.

Is there a workaround to do this on a shared host?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't access the config yourself, ask nicely. Some hosters are going to provide you with an alternative. Otherwise, you could use `LIKE`. Not a full substitute, but a workaround:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE searchcol LIKE '%abc%'
```